# Oracle SQL Regex OR statement

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

**SOFTWARE:** Oracle SQL

---

I have a regex `REGEXP_SUBSTR(M.ENDPOINTAPPLICATIONNAME,'[^\s]*.exe',1,1,'i')` that successfully matches

`EXCEL.EXE` to `EXCEL.EXE`

`Dropbox.exe` to `Dropbox.exe`

`1-2-3-4-hike.exe` to `1-2-3-4-hike.exe`

`shish boom bah.exe` to `bah.exe`

But I wish to also match

`MS Outlook` to `MS Outlook`

What is the `OR` statement in Oracle Regex such that it selects all text if the `[^\s]*.exe` is not found?

This is what I have (but doesn't work)

`REGEXP_SUBSTR(M.ENDPOINTAPPLICATIONNAME,'([^\s]*.exe)'|('.'),1,1,'i')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `|` has to be inside the regexp string, you shouldn't end the string.

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(M.ENDPOINTAPPLICATIONNAME,'([^\s]*.exe)|(.)',1,1,'i')
```

But `.` just matches a single character, not the whole string. You need `.*` to match everything. There's also no need for the grouping parentheses.

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(M.ENDPOINTAPPLICATIONNAME,'[^\s]*.exe|.*',1,1,'i')
```

However, this won't really do what you want. When matching a regexp, it looks for the first match in the input string, not the part of the input string that matches the first alternative in the regexp. Since `.*` matches `shish boom bah.exe`, it will return that whole string rather than just `bah.exe`.

You need to use `CASE` to pick the preferred alternative:

```
CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(M.ENDPOINTAPPLICATIONNAME, '\.exe', 'i')
     THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(M.ENDPOINTAPPLICATIONNAME,'\S*\.exe',1,1,'i')
     ELSE M.ENDPOINTAPPLICATIONNAME
END
```

Note that you should also escape `.` in the regexp, since it's normally a wildcard character. And `\S` is the same as `[^\s]`.

Comment: Hello @barmar thank you for your prompt and thorough answer!